# Any interest in listing cognates and false friends for languages?

Tags: discussion

I don't know of any online systematic lists of cognates and false friends. Would anyone be interested in starting them here as Community Wikis?

Comment: On the main site or the meta site?

Comment: @Tsundoku Which do you prefer? It doesn't matter to me.

Comment: If we do this at all, I would prefer to have those lists on the main site, where people are actually going to find them if they search the site.

Comment: @Tsundoku Certainly, main site then.